# Using awk to replace only once the delimiter between $4 and $5

Tags: replace, sed, awk

I'm really new in awk language and I'm suprised of all the power it has. (I discovered this today), because I have a file in this format:

```
test1;test2;test3;test4;test5;test6;test7
```

I need to output this in a new file and get this as result:

```
test1;test2;test3;test4 test5;test6;test7
```

Basically add ' ' between $4 and $5. I know there is a lot of questions about this but I'm not able to do what I want.

I was testing this code that I found somewhere here:

```
   for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
      printf "%s;", $i

   n = split($0,tmp,/  +/)

   for (i=6;i>=8;i++)
      printf ";%s", tmp[n-i]

   print ""
}
```

But I get as output something like:

```
test1;test2;test3;test4;test5;test6;;;
```

Can you please tell my what I'm doing wrong? and, there is another simple method like one-line code in awk to do this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with sed on this one. On the basis that the issue is "replace the 4th ; character" you can use this:

```
sed 's/;/ /4' <inputfile>
```

That'll output the result to stdout, or you can use "sed -i" to do it in place.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html

Comment: Where did you see this trick chooban ? First time I see it oO "4" is not known as a modifier !? oO

Comment: The info page for sed. Section 3.5 covers the 's' command. At least, that's where I looked this time. I probably used google the first time I needed it!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
echo "test1;test2;test3;test4;test5;test6;test7" | awk -F';' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i == 4) ? " " : ";"
}'
```

### Output

```
test1;test2;test3;test4 test5;test6;test7
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, your code works fine! I was totally wrong with my other code. Actually I'm using chooban one because it's more easy (only one line)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU awk you could use a similar solution to what *chooban* suggested:

```
 awk '{ $0=gensub(";", " ", "4") } 1'
```

The `1` at the end invokes the default block: `{ print $0 }`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm only using the command line (working in distance with SSH and a Raspberry Pi xD )

Comment: Right, I'm a little tired sory !!